# Is there any tool for aiding with explicit import of modules in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, import, module, conventions

After considering the reasons [here](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Import_modules_properly) to always import modules explicitly (with the exception of `Prelude`), I am trying to abide by this norm. However, this may sometimes be cumbersome. Is there any tool which would analyze working code and give a complete list of explicit imports?

Comment: If you compile with `ghc -v`, you can see all the imports in a section that starts with `Link Info: ((["-lHScryptohash-0.11.6", ....`.  This has some problems though....  First, you need to pull out the info and parse it, and second, it seems to hold more packages than you need.  I hesitate to promote this comment to an answer because of these problems, but perhaps this can help you anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the `-ddump-minimal-imports` flag for `ghc`.

The results are placed in the file `(module-name).imports`.

The `-fno-code` ghc option is also helpful here (to avoid the code generation phase.)

Comment: That shows the imports themselves, not the packages....  which are needed for the .cabal file.

Comment: True, but I don't think the OP was asking for that. For getting package names and versions it seems that `cabal init` does a pretty good job.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Just for the record – I used it in a sandbox with `cabal build --ghc-options="-ddump-minimal-imports -fno-code"`. From a clean state, `ar` complains about there being no object files, but regardless of that the build does what’s desired.

Comment: I have just noticed that, when using `#ifdef` conditional compilation, there is the possibility of some names not appearing in the output for `-ddump-minimal-imports`.

Comment: For stack the command is `stack build --ghc-options="-ddump-minimal-imports"`.